# SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query]

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I am using Symfony 2.8. I am currently experiencing this error. I try to uninstall and reinstall the elasticsearch and populate the cluster again by running `app/console fos:elastic:populate`. None of them fixes the problem. Here is my code.

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        website:
            types:
                blog:
                  mappings:
                      title: ~
                      content: ~
                      #description: ~
                      #category: ~
                  persistence:
                      driver: orm
                      model: CC\BlogBundle\Entity\BlogPost
                      provider: ~
                      listener:
                        immediate: ~
                      finder: ~
                job:
                    mappings:
                        position: ~
                        location: ~
                        description: ~
                        category: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: CC\JobBundle\Entity\Job
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
#                          immediate: ~
                        finder: ~
                care_recipient:
                    mappings:
                        zip: {index: not_analyzed}
                        type: {index: not_analyzed}
                        startDate:
                            { "type": "date", "format": "MM/dd/yyyy" }
                        endDate:
                            { "type": "date", "format": "MM/dd/yyyy" }
                        prefSmoke: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefLicense: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefInsurance: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefPets: {index: not_analyzed}
                        payment:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefHourlyRate: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefDay:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        availability:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                prefDay: {index: not_analyzed}
                                morning: {index: not_analyzed}
                                afternoon: {index: not_analyzed}
                                evening: {index: not_analyzed}
                        zipCode:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                                prefLocation: {index: not_analyzed}
#                        prefLocation:
#                            type: "nested"
#                            properties:
#                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefExperience:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefLiftWeight:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefFaith:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefLanguage:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefActivity:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefNonMedical:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefTitle:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: CC\UserBundle\Entity\CareRecipient
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
#                          immediate: ~
                        finder: ~
                care_provider:
                    mappings:
                        firstName: {index: not_analyzed}
                        lastName: {index: not_analyzed}
                        city: {index: not_analyzed}
                        state: {index: not_analyzed}
                        zip: {index: not_analyzed}
                        type: {index: not_analyzed}
                        startDate:
                            { "type": "date", "format": "MM/dd/yyyy" }
                        endDate:
                            { "type": "date", "format": "MM/dd/yyyy" }
                        prefSmoke: {index: not_analyzed}
                        allergyCat: {index: not_analyzed}
                        allergyDog: {index: not_analyzed}
                        isLicensed: {index: not_analyzed}
                        isInsured: {index: not_analyzed}
                        payment:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefHourlyRate: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefDay:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        availability:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                prefDay: {index: not_analyzed}
                                morning: {index: not_analyzed}
                                afternoon: {index: not_analyzed}
                                evening: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefLocation:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefExperience:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefLiftWeight:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefFaith:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefLanguage:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefActivity:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefNonMedical:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                        prefTitle:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                label: {index: not_analyzed}
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: CC\UserBundle\Entity\CareProvider
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
#                          immediate: ~
                        finder: ~
```

Now here is the error:

```
    Uncaught PHP Exception Elastica\Exception\ResponseException: "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[IQFDYA78S4qGwyJLJqm_dg][website][0]: SearchParseException[[website][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
  {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"nested":{"path":"prefTitle","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefTitle.label":[["Nurse Practitioner"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefExperience","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefExperience.label":["0-1"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefLiftWeight","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefLiftWeight.label":["25-50 lbs"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefNonMedical","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefNonMedical.label":[["Bathing","Grooming","Toileting","Medication Reminders","Grocery & Shopping","Transferring & Mobility","Exercise","Transportation","Meal Prep","Housekeeping","Companionship","Dementia Care"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefActivity","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefActivity.label":[["Skilled Nursing","Wound Care","Administer Medication","Palliative Care","Speech Therapy","Physical Therapy","Respiratory Therapy","Occupation Therapy","Hospice","DME","IV Therapy","Other"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefLocation","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefLocation.label":["Clear Lake Area"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"availability","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefDay":"M","morning":true}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"isLicensed":true}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}},{"bool":{}},{"bool":{}}],"should":[{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"isInsured":[true,false]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}]}}}
]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[website] script_score the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; }{[IQFDYA78S4qGwyJLJqm_dg][website][1]: SearchParseException[[website][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
  {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"nested":{"path":"prefTitle","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefTitle.label":[["Nurse Practitioner"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefExperience","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefExperience.label":["0-1"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefLiftWeight","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefLiftWeight.label":["25-50 lbs"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefNonMedical","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefNonMedical.label":[["Bathing","Grooming","Toileting","Medication Reminders","Grocery & Shopping","Transferring & Mobility","Exercise","Transportation","Meal Prep","Housekeeping","Companionship","Dementia Care"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefActivity","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefActivity.label":[["Skilled Nursing","Wound Care","Administer Medication","Palliative Care","Speech Therapy","Physical Therapy","Respiratory Therapy","Occupation Therapy","Hospice","DME","IV Therapy","Other"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefLocation","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefLocation.label":["Clear Lake Area"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"availability","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefDay":"M","morning":true}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"isLicensed":true}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}},{"bool":{}},{"bool":{}}],"should":[{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"isInsured":[true,false]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}]}}}
]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[website] script_score the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; }{[IQFDYA78S4qGwyJLJqm_dg][website][2]: SearchParseException[[website][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
  {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"nested":{"path":"prefTitle","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefTitle.label":[["Nurse Practitioner"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefExperience","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefExperience.label":["0-1"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefLiftWeight","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefLiftWeight.label":["25-50 lbs"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefNonMedical","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefNonMedical.label":[["Bathing","Grooming","Toileting","Medication Reminders","Grocery & Shopping","Transferring & Mobility","Exercise","Transportation","Meal Prep","Housekeeping","Companionship","Dementia Care"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefActivity","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefActivity.label":[["Skilled Nursing","Wound Care","Administer Medication","Palliative Care","Speech Therapy","Physical Therapy","Respiratory Therapy","Occupation Therapy","Hospice","DME","IV Therapy","Other"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefLocation","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefLocation.label":["Clear Lake Area"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"availability","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefDay":"M","morning":true}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"isLicensed":true}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}},{"bool":{}},{"bool":{}}],"should":[{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"isInsured":[true,false]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}]}}}
]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[website] script_score the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; }{[IQFDYA78S4qGwyJLJqm_dg][website][3]: SearchParseException[[website][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
  {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"nested":{"path":"prefTitle","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefTitle.label":[["Nurse Practitioner"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefExperience","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefExperience.label":["0-1"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefLiftWeight","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefLiftWeight.label":["25-50 lbs"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefNonMedical","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefNonMedical.label":[["Bathing","Grooming","Toileting","Medication Reminders","Grocery & Shopping","Transferring & Mobility","Exercise","Transportation","Meal Prep","Housekeeping","Companionship","Dementia Care"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefActivity","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefActivity.label":[["Skilled Nursing","Wound Care","Administer Medication","Palliative Care","Speech Therapy","Physical Therapy","Respiratory Therapy","Occupation Therapy","Hospice","DME","IV Therapy","Other"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefLocation","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefLocation.label":["Clear Lake Area"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"availability","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefDay":"M","morning":true}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"isLicensed":true}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}},{"bool":{}},{"bool":{}}],"should":[{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"isInsured":[true,false]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}]}}}
]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[website] script_score the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; }{[IQFDYA78S4qGwyJLJqm_dg][website][4]: SearchParseException[[website][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
  {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"nested":{"path":"prefTitle","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefTitle.label":[["Nurse Practitioner"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefExperience","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefExperience.label":["0-1"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefLiftWeight","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefLiftWeight.label":["25-50 lbs"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefNonMedical","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefNonMedical.label":[["Bathing","Grooming","Toileting","Medication Reminders","Grocery & Shopping","Transferring & Mobility","Exercise","Transportation","Meal Prep","Housekeeping","Companionship","Dementia Care"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefActivity","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefActivity.label":[["Skilled Nursing","Wound Care","Administer Medication","Palliative Care","Speech Therapy","Physical Therapy","Respiratory Therapy","Occupation Therapy","Hospice","DME","IV Therapy","Other"]]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"prefLocation","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefLocation.label":["Clear Lake Area"]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"availability","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"prefDay":"M","morning":true}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}}},{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"isLicensed":true}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}},{"bool":{}},{"bool":{}}],"should":[{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"filter":{"term":{"isInsured":[true,false]}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"2"}}]}}]}}]}}}
]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[website] script_score the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; }]" at /home/eleazar/Desktop/Projects/ccweb1/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php line 159
```

This code is running before. I don't know what was the problem. Please help me. thank you.

Comment: Please add the query that is resulting in error.

Comment: I already add the error message

Answer (score 0):

In the query there are two empty bool blocks which should be removed:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "prefTitle",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "function_score": {
                      "filter": {
                        "term": {
                          "prefTitle.label": [
                            [
                              "Nurse Practitioner"
                            ]
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "functions": [
                        {
                          "script_score": {
                            "script": "2"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "prefExperience",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "function_score": {
                      "filter": {
                        "term": {
                          "prefExperience.label": [
                            "0-1"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "functions": [
                        {
                          "script_score": {
                            "script": "2"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "prefLiftWeight",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "function_score": {
                      "filter": {
                        "term": {
                          "prefLiftWeight.label": [
                            "25-50 lbs"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "functions": [
                        {
                          "script_score": {
                            "script": "2"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "prefNonMedical",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "function_score": {
                      "filter": {
                        "term": {
                          "prefNonMedical.label": [
                            [
                              "Bathing",
                              "Grooming",
                              "Toileting",
                              "Medication Reminders",
                              "Grocery & Shopping",
                              "Transferring & Mobility",
                              "Exercise",
                              "Transportation",
                              "Meal Prep",
                              "Housekeeping",
                              "Companionship",
                              "Dementia Care"
                            ]
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "functions": [
                        {
                          "script_score": {
                            "script": "2"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "prefActivity",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "function_score": {
                      "filter": {
                        "term": {
                          "prefActivity.label": [
                            [
                              "Skilled Nursing",
                              "Wound Care",
                              "Administer Medication",
                              "Palliative Care",
                              "Speech Therapy",
                              "Physical Therapy",
                              "Respiratory Therapy",
                              "Occupation Therapy",
                              "Hospice",
                              "DME",
                              "IV Therapy",
                              "Other"
                            ]
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "functions": [
                        {
                          "script_score": {
                            "script": "2"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "prefLocation",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "function_score": {
                      "filter": {
                        "term": {
                          "prefLocation.label": [
                            "Clear Lake Area"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "functions": [
                        {
                          "script_score": {
                            "script": "2"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "availability",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "function_score": {
                      "filter": {
                        "term": {
                          "prefDay": "M",
                          "morning": true
                        }
                      },
                      "functions": [
                        {
                          "script_score": {
                            "script": "2"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "function_score": {
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "isLicensed": true
                    }
                  },
                  "functions": [
                    {
                      "script_score": {
                        "script": "2"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {}             <--------- remove this
        },
        {
          "bool": {}             <--------- remove this
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "function_score": {
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "isInsured": [
                        true,
                        false
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "functions": [
                    {
                      "script_score": {
                        "script": "2"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```